# How do I map ClipboardContentBinding to the DisplayPath of a combobox as part of a DataGridTemplateColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following DataGridTemplateColumn and I am trying to bind ClipboardContentBinding to the DisplayMemberPath path of the ComboBox. Is it possible? I can bind it to the SelectedCatchDetailWrapper.GUID using 
ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding SelectedCatchDetailWrapper.GUID}" but I want to map it to the DisplayMemberPath property of the combobox.

Categories is just an

```
    ObservableCollection<GuidLookupItem> Categories
```

```
    public class GuidLookupItem
    {
        public string GUID { get; set; }
        public string DisplayMember { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="CatchDetails" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding CatchDetailWrappers}"
           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCatchDetailWrapper, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!--Category-->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn ClipboardContentBinding="???????">
            <!--Category Header-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.CategoryText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <!--Category Cell-->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Categories, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                      IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                      TextSearch.TextPath="DisplayMember"
                      DisplayMemberPath="DisplayMember"
                      SelectedValuePath="GUID"  
                      SelectedValue="{Binding CategoryGuid, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your CategoryGuid property type on GuidLookupItem.

Then remove `SelectedValuePath="GUID"` because it cause runtime error.

Set
`SelectedValue="{Binding YourPropertyName, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

and `ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding YourPropertyName.DisplayMember}"`

```
public IEnumerable<YourType> CatchDetailWrappers { get; set; }
public class YourType
{
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }
    [...]
    public GuidLookupItem YourPropertyName { get; set; }
}
```